# Are radio telescopes finding radio-dark Nebulas

Tags: radio-astronomy, nebula

Are there "dark nebula" spots in the sky for radio telescopes?  By that I mean, are there portions in the sky where these telescopes do not receive any radio waves?   If so, do they match the visual dark nebula spots.

Comment: So you are looking for nebulas which absorb radio-frequencies emitted by the objects further behind? Which frequency range do you have in mind?

Comment: Those objects would have to have temperatures colder than the equivalent radio temperature - very unlikely, given that you have to equilibrate with a radiation field of 2.7 K at most.

Comment: @lB--rian I am just wondering in general if radio telescopes find spots in the sky in the same way that there are blank spots in the sky visually.